Best Practices for Manually Testing Email Verification with Only Real Test Data?
I don't have a lot of experience in manual testing. I'm writing test cases for manually testing email authentication for a login:

user enters email and password
user is launched to verification page with a text box for a code
user is sent an email with the code
user enters code and is logged in

all I'm allowed to use right now is my own company email address. I'm the only QA in my company so technically that would work for now, but wow it feels shoddy. Would the best practice be to put logging into my email account directly in the test steps? Is there some kind of workaround that I'm missing? Is this as crazy as it sounds to me??

If the system is architected well, you should be able to remove the dependency on sending live emails.
If your application connects to an SMTP server directly, then a tool like MailCatcher would work. In development and test environments, you can include MailCatcher as a dependency and use application configuration to send email to MailCatcher, allowing developers and testers to view outbound email without sending it to an email address.
If your application uses mail APIs, such as those offered by services like SendGrid, you can determine whether they provide a test mode that allows you to interact with the API without transmitting emails (and exposing them through a console) or by sending emails to fixed addresses. If the service doesn't offer a test configuration, configuring the application to run in a test mode that doesn't use the service's APIs would work. You may need end-to-end tests in some environments to ensure you're using the APIs correctly, but bypassing the APIs and exposing information about the email through another mechanism would be useful for testing.
The important thing to remember is that, in most cases, sending the email is the responsibility of something outside the system. Unless you've written your own mail server and are testing it, you can assume that your off-the-shelf mail server or mail service is tested and works. The part of the system under test is the fact that a message is published to that API or mail server (and you can intercept that message to get your verification code), that logging in with a correct verification code is successful, and attempting to log in with an incorrect verification code is unsuccessful.


Would the best practice be to put logging into my email account directly in the test steps? Is there some kind of workaround that I'm missing?

First, this is not "crazy!" Right now, you lack experience and knowledge. The good thing is that you are aware of this, questioning it, thinking how it "feels shoddy," etc. So many people lack the awareness and curiosity to ask questions! Keep asking questions and lean into this sense of curiosity!
There are many things we don't know how your system-under-test is setup. But your question is mainly about the test cases you need to consider. Here are some things to consider:

Login using a known email address (this is what you're currently doing).
Login using incorrect email and password.
Login using correct email and incorrect password.
Login using incorrect email format.
Login using correct email and many different password formats.

There's more to writing good test cases than just the proper login usage. You want to see how it operates using wrong data, missing data, malformed data, etc. You want to see how those error messages work. This is also how you'll find good bugs and ensure the app is working from multiple perspectives. This is the fun part!
Now, more to the point of your concern about real email and seeing a response.
Most email providers allow one user to use "fake" email addresses if you know how. I've setup free accounts on Gmail, Outlook just for testing these scenarios. These platforms allow you to use + account formats. Let's proceed using Gmail.
If you have an email like "username@gmail.com", you can use the following:

username+123@gmail.com. Anything after the + sign can be changed. Gmail knows to map it to "username@gmail.com". It's called "plus addressing." You have to put the + after your username and before the @ for it to work. And, you can do this unlimited times!
username.somename@gmail.com. Same thing here. Gmail knows to map anything after the . in the user "username@gmail.com".

Personally, I use plus addressing when I need to use more than one valid email address when testing. Need to setup multiple accounts on the system you're testing? Use plus addressing. To your system, they are separate user accounts!

"all I'm allowed to use right now is my own company email address."

Who says? Do you have a requirement for this? Some legal restriction? Unless you're dealing with government work, need clearances, or have some legal standard you 100% need to follow, then you can and should use outside email accounts like Gmail.
